# Question related to "RELATED RATES"

Tags: calculus

Two cars start moving from the same point. One travels south at 60 miles/hr and the other travels west at 25 miles/hr. At what rate is the distance between the cars increasing two hours later?

I feel like the question is incomplete. Please help me in providing the solution if the question is complete.

Answer (score 1):

The question is complete.  You should calculate the location of each car as a function of time, then use the distance formula to calculate the distance between the cars as a function of time.  Take the derivative of this distance, plug in $t=2$ hours, and you are there.